# how to use virtual environment for python2.7 on Mac M1？

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, apple-m1, virtual-environment

My old code project's process environment is python2.7, I bought a new Mac M1 days ago, however, after install conda by miniforge, I found it that only supports python3,and virtualenv is so on, anybody help?

Comment: It looks the upgrade of your project to python 3 is long delayed/overdue.

Comment: It seems that your proposal is indeed the best

Comment: Have you tried installing Python 2 any other way…? E.g. http://brew.sh?

Comment: Do you mean that the problem occurred by original Python(Mac's own python2.7)? I have always feel that the problem caused by M1, ARM 64

Comment: Conda alone won't solve this because Python 2 was sunset prior to M1, so there are no native builds. Instead, you'll have to go through Rosetta 2 (Apple's x86_64 emulator) or Docker or similar.

Comment: Use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/). If it cant be installed normally, try running Terminal in x86 compatibility mode.